# Remove zebra stripe from certain rows

Tags: css, css-tables

I have a table that I currently do zebra striping on with the rows, even and odd which works fine. My problem is that I also have a class that is used to indicate the new rows which a different color style. It seems that this new class is being over thrown by the zebra stripe CSS, is there a way around this? Any tips or suggestions appreciated, thanks.

Here is a bit of CSS that controls this table

```
   #table tbody tr:nth-child(odd){
    background-color: #cccccc; color:black;
     }
   #table tbody tr:nth-child(even){
   background: #EBEBEB; color: #7D7D7D;
    }
   #table tbody tr:nth-child(2n+1):hover{
        cursor:pointer;
        /* add gradient */
        background-color: #808080;
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#909090), to(#606060));
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #909090, #606060);
        color: #dadada;
        font-weight: ;
    }
  #table tbody tr:nth-child(2n):hover{
        cursor:pointer;
        /* add gradient */
        background-color: #808080;
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#909090),        to(#606060));
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #909090, #606060);
        color: #dadada;

    }
  .new {
    background-color: #760086;
    color:white;
       }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put the CSS for the zebra-stripping rows before the codes for the newly created elements, then it should be just fine:

```css
p:nth-child(2n+1){
    /*blah*/
}
p:nth-child(2n){
    /*blah*/
}
p.new{
    /*blah*/
}
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/ZFcKs/

Comment: That is what I thought too, but alas no dice yet. I just removed the zebra css and the new class is being applied. :S

Comment: @kabuto178 - Did you put `!important` in any of your code? This might override the code for the `new` class.

Comment: No, I did not use !important in my css. Should I be?

Comment: @kabuto178 - You shouldn't, and if you didn't use then it should work like in my example. You will have to show some of your code so that we can find where the problem is at.

Comment: sure no problem, and when i inspect the element i see the class attached to the li is new and the others read

Comment: the other tr tags have a class of read, and the first tr in the table has a class of new. The tr with the 'new' class is still being stuck with the striped colors I had set with CSS. I shall edit in some of my CSS

Comment: Because the div containing this new message class is updated dynamically, i ended up using js to add the class manually.